# Trouble understanding the bounds for marginal probability integrals

Tags: probability

Say we have a question such as this:

> $f(x,y)= C\;\;\; 0<x<1,\; y>0,\; y<2x\;\;\;$ and $0$ otherwise.

I can calculate that $C=1$ from evaluating $$\int_0^1\left( \int_0^{2x}C \; dy \right) dx=1$$.Now to calculate the marginal I get $$f_X(x)=\int_0^{2x}dy=2x$$ However for $f_Y(y)$ I'm not sure which one of these two I would use and why: $$\int_{\frac{y}{2}}^1 dx=1-\frac{y}{2}\;\;\; OR \;\; \int_0^1dx=1$$ Does the marginal always have to contain the parameter? I'm thinking the second one since I already used the inequality $y<2x$ in the previous marginal? Or is it just completely separate, like you don't care you already used it, just that $x$ is between $\frac{y}{2}$ and 1? Sorry for all the questions :)

$\textbf{EDIT:}$
Also say I want to find the conditional probability $P(X>\frac{1}{3}|Y=1/2)$ is this zero? As a continuous probability distribution is zero at every point. I know I'd have to calculate the conditional probability distribution $f_{X|Y}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $y\in(0,2)$:

$$f_{Y}\left(y\right)=\int f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}y}f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}y}^{1}f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)dx=$$$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}y}0dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}y}^{1}1dx=1-\frac{1}{2}y$$

---

**Edit concerning your edit.**

Normally for a fixed $y_{0}$ as the conditional PDF $f_{X\mid Y=y_{0}}$
one takes the function that is prescribed by: $$x\mapsto c^{-1}f_{X,Y}\left(x,y_{0}\right)$$
where $c:=\int f_{X,Y}\left(x,y_{0}\right)dx$.

Doing that here with
$y_{0}=\frac{1}{2}$ we find $c=\int f_{X,Y}\left(x,\frac{1}{2}\right)dx=\int_{\frac{1}{4}}^{1}dx=\frac{3}{4}$
so that $f_{X\mid Y=\frac{1}{2}}$ is prescribed by $x\mapsto\frac{4}{3}$
if $x\in\left(\frac{1}{4},1\right)$ and $x\mapsto0$ otherwise. Based
on that we find $$P\left(X>\frac{1}{3}\mid Y=\frac{1}{2}\right)=\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{\infty}f_{X\mid Y=\frac{1}{2}}\left(x\right)dx=\frac{4}{3}\int_{\frac{1}{3}}^{1}dx=\frac{8}{9}$$

But it must be admitted that this is somehow "questionable".
On the set $\left\{ \left(x,y\right)\mid y=\frac{1}{2}\right\} $
we could change the values of the original PDF almost as much as we
like without affecting its functionality as PDF for the original
distribution. This because the set has Lebesguemeasure $0$. The only
demands are that it stays a nonnegative and measurable function. However,
if we do things like that then we can end up with a totally different
conditional PDF $f_{X\mid Y=\frac{1}{2}}$.